# outlook add-in not working in read mode

Tags: outlook, add-in

My Outlook Add-in works fine in compose mode, but it always not clickable in read mode, However, all my other colleges' outlook add-in work fine both in compose and read mode, does anyone know this issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "not clickable" mean?

Comment: not clickable is : the icon is gray (as shown in the first figure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Outlook Add-ins overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#mailbox-items-available-to-add-ins) ...

Outlook does not activate add-ins if the current message item, in a compose or read form, is one of the following:

- Protected by Information Rights Management (IRM), in S/MIME format or encrypted in other ways for protection. A digitally signed message is an example since digital signing relies on one of these mechanisms.
- A delivery report or notification that has the message class IPM.Report.*, including delivery and Non-Delivery Report (NDR) reports, and read, non-read, and delay notifications.
- A draft (does not have a sender assigned to it), or in the Outlook Drafts folder.
- A .msg or .eml file which is an attachment to another message.
- A .msg or .eml file opened from the file system.
- In a shared mailbox, in another user's mailbox, in an archive mailbox, or in a public folder.
- Using a custom form.

You most likely have one of the situation listed above, for example use a custom form or messages are digitally signed, use of public folders, etc.

Comment: Thanks your answer, I checked all of them and resolved. The reason is I am in Conversational View, After changing to Classic View of Outlook, it fixed